# VBA return 2 variants in MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel, math, office-2013

This is the start to a simple mathematical theorem demonstration.

When I run this macro neither Coefficient nor Degree appear in MsgBox.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Degree, Coefficient
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
Cells(1, 2).Value = Degree
Cells(2, 2).Value = Coefficient
    If IsNumeric(Degree) = True Then
    Else: MsgBox "IsNumeric(Degree)=False)"
        If IsNumeric(Coefficient) = True Then
        Else: MsgBox "IsNumeric(Coefficient)=False"
            MsgBox Coefficient & "x^" & Degree
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: new version of code as suggested by comments (still doesn't work):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Function1()
Dim Degree, Coefficient
MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
Degree = Cells(1, 2).Value
Coefficient = Cells(2, 2).Value
    If IsNumeric(Degree) = True Then
    Else: MsgBox "IsNumeric(Degree)=False)"
        If IsNumeric(Coefficient) = True Then
        Else: MsgBox "IsNumeric(Coefficient)=False"
            MsgBox Coefficient & "x^" & Degree
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `Degree` and `Coefficient`.  Instead, you assign cells B1 and B2 to null values because Degree and Coefficient were never assigned values.  Are those lines supposed to be the other way around? Such that `Degree = Cells(1, 2).Value` ??

Comment: The order of assignment doesn't look right, try `Degree = Cells(1, 2).Value` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Still doesn't work.

Comment: ...not to be silly, but you have data in your cells `B1 and B2` yeah? Are you working with multiple worksheets/workbooks?  What is the value in `B1` and `B2`?  If you step through your macro (press `F8`), after the `Degree = Cells(...` line, hover your mouse over "Degree" - what does it show? It should pop up with the value that's in `B2`.  Looking at your edited code, if your `Degree` is not being set, then how are you getting message boxes? I'd think `If IsNumeric(Degree)` would be `FALSE`, therefore no `If` statement should run, therefore no message boxes would show?

Comment: Your structure of outer `If` statement is wrong, all code is placed in `Else` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to rewrite your procedure something like this:

```
Sub Function1()
    Dim Degree, Coefficient
    MsgBox "Enter polynomial by terms."
    Degree = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Coefficient = Cells(2, 2).Value

    If Len(Trim(Degree)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Degree) Then
        MsgBox "Degree is numeric"
    Else
        MsgBox "Degree is not numeric. Exiting"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Len(Trim(Coefficient)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Coefficient) Then
        MsgBox "Coefficient is numeric"
    Else
        MsgBox "Coefficient is not numeric. Exiting"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox Coefficient & "x^" & Degree

End Sub
```

In cell B1, type 1. In cell B2, type 2. Run the procedure and you should see expected outcome. You can build from there on.

Comment: I think OP would benefit from doing If statements as above, instead of using the colons - as @user3964075 pointed out, it can cause some confusion.